# Mysql query, return only records which date is not overlapped with date of other records

Tags: mysql

To track orders i need order id from orders table and check orderdates table that order is made on specific date range. Using following query i can get id's but it will return id 3 also which is not needed.

Example: See orderdates table. First date of id 3 is overlapping with last date of id 2.

How i have to change query that id is not returned if it's first date is overlapping some other id's last date or is it even possible?

```
SELECT id
FROM orders
WHERE id in(
SELECT id
FROM orderdates
WHERE 
orderdate BETWEEN '2017-06-01' AND '2017-06-30'
GROUP BY id);
```

```
orders  
id  sent
1   1
2   1
3   1
```

```
orderdates  
id  orderdate
1   2017-6-10
1   2017-6-11
1   2017-6-12
1   2017-6-13
2   2017-6-14
2   2017-6-15
2   2017-6-16
2   2017-6-17 <--- Last date of id 2
3   2017-6-17 <--- First date of id 3
3   2017-6-18
3   2017-6-19
3   2017-6-20
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it return id = 3 when it is inside your date parameters?

Comment: Yes, 3 is returned but can it somehow filtered if date is interleved with other date?

Comment: what is the logic though? if a date overlaps get rid of all the ids of the highest overlapping id's date?

Comment: You are not clear. What does "orderdates.orderdate is not interleaving with any other date like it does now" mean? Also, everything after that. Please use enough sentences to clearly say what you mean. PS When you edit your question, don't just append, rewrite to be clear.

Comment: I have read this a number of times and I just don't understand why you would do this. Surely the relationship between orders and orderdates is by id and it doesn't matter if there is date overlap?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Why is 3 not needed? For arbitrary input, what is the output? Do you want the top two? Or what? Show desired output. Your question has improved but you are still not clear. You are still too terse. You are not saying what you need. Important: read & act on [mcve]. (Don't focus on changing wrong queries. Focus on querying for parts that are relevant to the answer  & putting them together.)

Comment: I told what is the starting point, goal and the problem. I think there is enogh information to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this where I compare the min date for every id against the max date for every id

```
select u.*
from t u
where u.id not in
(
select z.id
from
(
select s.*,t.id tid,t.mindt tmindt,t.maxdt tmaxdt
from
(
select id, min(dt) mindt,max(dt) maxdt
from t 
group by id
order by id
) s
join 
(select id, min(dt) mindt,max(dt) maxdt
from t 
group by id
order by id
) t on 
    t.id <> s.id and 
    t.maxdt = s.mindt
) z
) 
order by u.id,u.dt
```

given this

```
truncate table t;
insert into t values
(1,'2017-01-01'),(1,'2017-01-02'),
(2,'2017-01-03'),(2,'2017-01-04'),
(3,'2017-01-04')
```

results in

```
+------+------------+
| id   | dt         |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2017-01-01 |
|    1 | 2017-01-02 |
|    2 | 2017-01-03 |
|    2 | 2017-01-04 |
+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

given this

```
truncate table t;
insert into t values
(1,'2017-01-01'),(1,'2017-01-02'),
(2,'2017-01-03'),(2,'2017-01-04'),
(3,'2017-01-04'),
(4,'2017-01-04'),(4,'2017-01-06');
```

Result

```
+------+------------+
| id   | dt         |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2017-01-01 |
|    1 | 2017-01-02 |
|    2 | 2017-01-03 |
|    2 | 2017-01-04 |
+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Given

```
truncate table t;
insert into t values
(1,'2017-01-01'),(1,'2017-01-02'),
(2,'2017-01-03'),(2,'2017-01-04'),
(3,'2017-01-04'),
(4,'2017-01-05'),(4,'2017-01-06');
```

result

```
+------+------------+
| id   | dt         |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 2017-01-01 |
|    1 | 2017-01-02 |
|    2 | 2017-01-03 |
|    2 | 2017-01-04 |
|    4 | 2017-01-05 |
|    4 | 2017-01-06 |
+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```